# How do I find upper bound for nth prime number?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, functions, prime-numbers

I'm writing a program that finds the nth prime number, so if n was 10, the answer would be 29. I need to find an upper bound to search through though so if n was 10, the upper bound would be 30 (or any number before the next prime number which is 31).

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems a lot easier to sieve (I have no idea if there exist any good bounds).

Comment: Wikipedia: [Approximations for the nth prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number)

Comment: Also see the questions:

  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507178/most-efficient-algorithm-for-nth-prime-deterministic-and-probabilistic
and
  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411346/how-do-i-findisolate-the-n-th-prime-number

As they give ideas for how to efficiently implement your actual program (find nth prime) for relatively large inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The number of primes below a given number, $\pi(x)$ can be estimated by:

$\pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{\ln(x)}$.

If you can find a "good" way to invert that function (and add maybe 20% uncertainty in there for small numbers), you can find the estimated upper bound.

Comment: The $r = \pi \ln \pi$ and $s = \pi (\ln \pi + \ln \ln \pi)$ are first and second-order approximations  for retrieving $x$ from costrom's formula.  For $\pi = 10$, these yield $r=23$ and $s=31$.

Comment: Only an aproximation : prime (n)=n*(ln (n)+ln (ln (n))-0.955) whit error small 4000 if n <10^7.It is a shapr approximation