# find $x$ given arbitrary $\pi(x)$

Tags: prime-numbers

When seeking the *n*th prime, how would one determine (or approximate) $x$, given a $\pi(x)$ value?

I've read that $x / log(x)$ is a decent approximation of primes below $x$, but nothing about the reverse.

I'm seeking an algorithm that can be easily implemented.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348247/inverse-of-prime-counting-function and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131683/asymptotic-bounds-on-pi-1x-inverse-prime-counting-function

Comment: $n$th prime number is approximately $n\ln n$. This follows from prime number theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For prime numbers $p_k$ you have $\pi(p_k)=k$, exactly.

Because the prime number theorem gives the approximation $p_k \sim k\log k,$ then the number $x$ for which $\pi(x)=k$ is approximately $k\log k$ with an known associated error.

Any $x$ in the interval $p_{k}\leq x<p_{k+1}$ gives $\pi(x)=k,$ so as you might expect,

$p_k\sim x\sim k\log k,$

and as you might or might not expect, $p_k\sim p_{k+1}.$ When implementing an algorithm using the p.n.t. approximation it may be important to keep the error in mind. [Dusart's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) error bounds are very useful.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I had read about k log k, but when I looked back, my eyes landed on x / log x and I got mixed up.  I ended up increasing k by 13% and generating primes < n where n = k log k.  I couldn't successfully implement Dusart's bounds.  Why 13%?  Because 12% didn't always yield a large enough n in my tests.  [code](http://exercism.io/submissions/8eec62f895a449d888ecd25523f083a7)