# Simplifying logarithms for inverse of the prime counting function

Tags: prime-numbers

I am writing a prime number sieve in software. I want to be able to return the first $n$ primes, where $n$ is an argument to the sieve function.

In order to do this efficiently, I would like to be able to allocate an array of integers that I *know* can hold the first $n$ primes at a minimum. This means the sieve will be just big enough, or too big, but never too small.

What I need is to reverse the prime counting function: instead of computing "number of primes below a value" I need "value equal to or greater than prime #n".

For example: if I ask for the first ten primes, I should be able to compute that $f(10)$ is some value equal to or greater than $29$. It does not need to be a tight bound, but should not be wildly greater than its bound (i.e. $f(n)$ should not evaluate to $n^2$).

---

Starting with [Wikipedia's prime-counting article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), I see that:

$$
\Pi(n) < {1.25506n \over \ln(n)}
$$

Great! This inequality means that if I can find *n*, I only have to sieve once without copying potentially millions of numbers around in memory more than once.

$\Pi(n)$ is the argument to my sieve function: it is the number of primes I am trying to find. $n$ is unknown: it is the size of the sieve I need to use. If I restate the above inequality as an equality relating the number of primes $q$ with the sieve size $n$, I get:

$$
q = {1.25506n \over \ln(n)}
$$

$$
1.25506n = q \ln(n)
$$

$$
n = {q \ln(n) \over 1.25506}
$$

$$
{n \over \ln(n)} = {q \over 1.25506}
$$

Since $q$ is known and I am trying to find $n$, I need to isolate $n$ and state it in terms of $q$ and constants. However, I am not sure how to get rid of the $\ln(n)$: any advice? This should be easily computable in Java, so preferably avoiding calculus or anything not in the [`java.lang.Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class would be ideal. If there is a way to approximate this function while still holding the post-condition (sieve is guaranteed to be large enough to hold $n$ primes) that is acceptable as well.

---

Note: this is similar to, but not the same as, [Inverse of prime counting function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1348247/) due to the specific requirements and help requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logarithms are base $e \approx 2.71828,$ as in The Prime Number Theorem

For $n \geq 6,$
$$ p_n < n ( \log n + \log \log n ) $$
This is  (3.13) on page 69 of [Rosser and Schoenfeld (1962)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807)

For $n \geq 1,$
$$ p_n > n  \log n  $$

Comment: For $1 <= n < 6$ I can hard-code a value that is microseconds of difference in running time: still, good to know for completeness sake.

Comment: @Snowman I don't understand your response. First I put the upper bound; since $\log \log 2 < 0$ it does not work right away, but does for $p_n$ once $n \geq 6.$  The lower bound $p_n > n \log n$ works for all $n.$ Note that Rosser took $p_1 = 2.$

Comment: this is feeding into an algorithm on a computer - I don't need to compute logarithms on such small numbers, I can hard-code a value and performance will be fine.